# Subshell stdout n tcsh

Tags: csh, tcsh

In bash I get the stdout of a subshell block and assign it to a varaiable like:

```
$ VAL="$(ls)"
```

How can this be done in tcsh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use backticks to get the output and use `set` to assign it to a variable

examples:

```
    $ set val=`ls`
    $ set val=`ls | grep foo`
```

to clear the variable use `unset val`

See http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html for more examples and information on csh / tcsh